# foundation sticky does not work and remove markup when initialised from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, zurb-foundation, sticky

I am trying to make an element sticky without touching the HTML.

I tried to follow the documentation but i don't know where did i missed something.

I know there have been a similiar  [bug](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/issues/8156)
 but i use the patched (6.3.1) version

```js
var elem = new Foundation.Sticky($('.another'));
```

```css
.item{
  height: 120vh;
}
.another{
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.3.1/js/foundation.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.3.1/css/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="item">
  item
</div>
<div class="another">
  another
</div>
<div class="item">
  item
</div>
```

and a [pen](https://codepen.io/fawmi/pen/eEdxqM)

Comment: why are you including JS - v6.3.1 and CSS - v6.3.0, two different versions?

Comment: it does not make any difference as it is a minor version difference, but updated both to 3.1

Comment: you need to include foundation.sticky.js , i think

Comment: no i do not, as i have included ´foundation.js´(which includes all plugins)

Comment: http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/sticky.html --- refer javascript Reference section. I think you must include sticky.js

Comment: You should include sticky.js if you do not have foundation.js or foundation.min.js included in your page.
have a look at source code of foundation.js you will see that it has sticky.js in its self